# Use multi selection along all values for same y-value marked points

Tags: vega-lite

I have a vega-lite visualization in kibana. The config goes like:

```
encoding: {
    x: {field: "time", timeUnit: "yearmonthdaydatehoursminutes", type: "temporal", axis : {title: null}}
    y: {field: "user", type: "nominal", axis : {title: null}}
}

layer : [
  {  
  "selection": {
    "select": {"type": "multi"}
  },
  "mark": { "type" : "point", "cursor": "pointer"},
  "encoding": {
    "opacity" : {"condition" : {"selection": "select", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.3}
  }
]
```

This basically multi selects based on clicking the point in visualization as shown below:

[image: Multi Select]

**Requirement**: I want to select all values falling on the same y-axis on one click of any one point (not only that point as in figure). Is this possible through vega-lite? Basically need an `if` condition with the y value of selected point.

I went over the documentation (though it was haunting) and some other examples to figure out, but no help. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the selection to apply to all points with the same y-axis value, you can pass `encodings=["y"]` within the selection specification:

```
"selection": {"select": {"type": "multi", "encodings": ["y"]}}
```

There is no way for selections to respond when clicking the background of the chart. But a nice trick to achieve this is to create a transparent background element to respond to clicks, and to use `"nearest": true` within your selection to allow clicking anywhere on the chart surface. Here is an example using Vega-Lite JSON ([view live in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBECmB2DGB7AJgS1gc0gLjMSAnjnpAC4EAO0xksiAtugIYA2kANFAGarQvI0ArgGdoAJw5RSqUi2q5YgliwC+K9uCgsmBccQDamiKAimo9JmIDWxfOSo0xS6p0iIKTeDKK4ADOqNTSFE5eGlEWFtAs2C+aDDbMkp5cyVpSRgEFHQMYQNCSABdV1hoS2hhUmJSJ2gVaLB6swCzEzNzSxtcO2SaCkR0Ktd4QTFhRAlcSH7BvRb2zKQ0TCj2oPdPb1W1oKRYNHDI7sgAN1ZBFIBGVxD4w5pbhPmdqDOWC+JfADoAZgaIZ4LAAe2xeSQcU1I0Ho-TErA4-yCPD4AkhqHoLkREDI6OgAFVYDIaLpLPQIqQABbIJhQimIUbCRiKKF5DQvbHSWQpRTKRFNdr8gGaYqaSDU0hMUGvc4VAwNOy4miXACcAHZfABaXyXDU-S4AFV8vmwRpN3yNFoATNrlRkRHopgAhSCA4w4jFKtWa3yWjWWgAchuNpqNXwtRutKrtokmUGdrpI0g9UxV6q1P11BpDwfN4cjttc9tjkAAwi62e0FcmoKnvQAWXW+INms1hvM26MOqAAUXL8vdKUgta1AFZM83s22rR3CzGaL2E1XB8PfAA2RsTnNTiMzqBFmgAMT7ayXnrTvlV4+zrfDPt3kH3UyPi4HZ+9-qvOZv7ajs67kAAQWPStXxTL0tWVDdr1DW9807YtnwrVpQJrcDLk1PVN2-adfz3OcpiAl8k2XNCdR+JtoNzHCCzw-8FyQ0xTzAtNLl9TDKO3O9cIffCoEIhi3WIs8dW1T8Wxgn8aJ4-8ABFgOQoTmJE30AywiTqPgmgyyIxUlPTMTJ1g+9HygbSBMTXTUNVESG3ItSqJ3biTMA+TGJQoc1REsd2K-dTHKk5y5J06sPOsrV1zsjijKc3jIHo-tFKskTLx88SHK4gLYqC8ymKSrUP1SwzJM0gjXMEyzQpEyDIt89K4L-Yt+ISirUx1dCDK3aLMtksqLJC1qNUuMiKNqzj6to4t4xy9yBtYjrsP8kqe163LQt9UTCs64qGsPFaZrVdaVOVeyxuM2KmpPfbVXWjNNoWjKlsgKbmv6g6tVska0tOmKeuCkjrtHea-Ienanz2xK1vCqDRq6x7nsuiHU3WlKsxh7aJt2v6z3WgrUa+2HQb4l1AkKTR6hUIA)):

```
{
  "encoding": {"y": {"type": "nominal", "field": "user", "title": null}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "opacity": 0},
      "selection": {
        "select": {"type": "multi", "encodings": ["y"], "nearest": true}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "cursor": "pointer"},
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 1, "selection": "select"},
          "value": 0.3
        },
        "x": {
          "type": "temporal",
          "field": "time",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdatehoursminutes",
          "title": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"time": "1970-01-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "B"},
      {"time": "1970-02-28T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "B"},
      {"time": "1970-03-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "C"},
      {"time": "1970-04-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "E"},
      {"time": "1970-05-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "E"},
      {"time": "1970-06-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1970-07-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1970-08-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1970-09-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1970-10-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1970-11-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "E"},
      {"time": "1970-12-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1971-01-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "D"},
      {"time": "1971-02-28T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "C"},
      {"time": "1971-03-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "C"},
      {"time": "1971-04-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1971-05-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "D"},
      {"time": "1971-06-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "E"},
      {"time": "1971-07-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "D"},
      {"time": "1971-08-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1971-09-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1971-10-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "D"},
      {"time": "1971-11-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "B"},
      {"time": "1971-12-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "E"},
      {"time": "1972-01-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1972-02-29T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"},
      {"time": "1972-03-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "B"},
      {"time": "1972-04-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "D"},
      {"time": "1972-05-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1972-06-30T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "B"},
      {"time": "1972-07-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "F"},
      {"time": "1972-08-31T00:00:00.000002019", "user": "A"}
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]